# http works fine in mobile browser, but https totally lags in mobile browser

Tags: https

Im doing a web based mobile application. uses tomcat as well. when i edit the tomcat to use https for my front end application basically all the jsp and servlets, it totally lags in mobile browser suchs as android. In iphone safari, it is worse, server connection error.

f.y.i, http works fine and fast.

Does anyone has any experience in this? does the certificate plays a part in the lagging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use online tools to make sure nothing is wrong with your certificate. example [DigiCert](http://www.digicert.com/help/).
Also check in your browser if there is a problem with the certificate (Chrome makes easy to check this, click on the secure icon at the left of the URL).

If all I said above is file I think the problem is from your HTTP server configuration.

Are you using port 443 and did you change default values?

Comment: Currently, i do not have any certificate and thus there will be the warning question upon going to the homepage of my site. 

And i use port 8443. the default specified in Tomcat server.xml file.